# Defining and inputing an array of strings with whitespaces in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, debugging

A array of strings has to be defined and taken as input for the purpose of finding some particular characters in the input in C++. I have been provided maximum number of lines `n` and maximum number of characters in each line `c`.

```
string lines[n];
for (int i=0; i<2000; i++) 
   cin.get(lines[i],c);
```

This code does not work as the arguments for`cin.get()` do not match.

Comment: What about using `std::getline()` You may get a grasp what `cin.get()` does, when you take a look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: `getline()` gives the same error

Comment: Should I not use the string library and use character arrays.

Comment: You should prefer `std::string` to character arrays.

Comment: @RohanSharma `std::getline(std::cin,lines[i]);` should just work fine. As mentioned read the documentation of the functions you use.

Comment: @Ron why are strings preferred  over character arrays?

Answer (score 0):

So defining it as a character array works.

```
char lines[n][c]={'\0'};
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    cin.getline(lines[i],c);

for(int i=0; i<n && lines[i]; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<c && lines[i][j]; j++)
        cout << lines[i][j];
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `cin.getline(lines[i],c);` You should have read my comment more thorough. `cin.getline()` isn't the same as `std::getline()`. And no, you shouldn't use `char` arrays, but `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing `maximum number of lines n and maximum number of characters in each line c`.

The istruction `lines[n]` simply declares an array of `char` of size `n`. Then inside the loop, you store from your std::in only **1** character of what you provide with `std::cin` since `lines[i]` can store only **1** `char` (This is its definition).

A solution is the following:

```
std::string lines[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, lines[i]);

    if (lines[i].size() > c)
       lines[i].resize(c); // to read only c characters
}
```